# Limit of sin(x) as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits, fourier-transform

This question comes from Fourier Transforms, specifically the evaluation of $\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi iat})$. Normally I see this derived by first finding the Inverse FT of a delta function, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\delta(\omega-a)) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\omega-a) e^{2\pi i \omega t}\,d\omega = e^{2\pi i at}
\end{align}
But suppose we wanted to be stubborn and directly evaluate
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi i a t}) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i a t} e^{-2\pi i \omega t} \,dt
\end{align}
It should work, right? Why wouldn't it? If we continue, we get to

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi i at}) &= \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{-x}^x e^{2\pi i  (a - \omega) t} \,dt  \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi(a-\omega)}\lim_{x \to \infty}\sin(2\pi(a-\omega) x) \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi (a - \omega)}\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)
\end{align}

Now, how do we convincingly evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)$? If I didn't have the context of evaluating a Fourier Transform, I would simply answer that the limit doesn't exist.

However, in this case I know what the answer *should* be, but I don't at all understand why it works or how to make it rigorous. It seems to contradict my previous understanding of limits.

Comment: The limit does not exist; you've proved that $e^{2\pi i a t}$ is not an integrable function. The "Fourier transform" you discuss is actually a generalized Fourier transform; it's very useful, but one shouldn't expect procedures related to integrable functions and regular Fourier transforms to apply.

Comment: Is it possible to generalize the notion of integration to match the generalized Fourier Transform? Or a way to directly evaluate $\mathcal{F}(e^{2\pi i at})$ that does not make use of the inverse fourier transform?